# Differentiation with square roots - check my work =)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, roots

Question:
Differentiate

√ x + 3x 
 (all is a square root)

I did function of a function rule

= (x<sup>2</sup>+3x)<sup>0.5</sup> *'* 

 = 0.5(x<sup>2</sup> + 3x) (2x+3) 

= (2x + 3) ÷ 2(x<sup>2</sup> + 3x)

Is that correct?

Thanks

Comment: I think you should check the power of $(x^2+3x)$ in the answer.

Comment: this question does not have an answer because it is not from the book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is nearly correct. What Archis is referring to is your use of the power rule. Remember, the power rule for derivatives says $\frac{d}{du}u^{n} = nu^{n-1}$. So when you take the derivative of $(x^{2}+3x)^{1/2}$ you will get

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}(x^{2}+3x)^{1/2} &= \frac{1}{2}\cdot (x^{2}+3x)^{\color{red}{1/2-1}}\cdot(2x+3) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\cdot (x^{2}+3x)^{\color{red}{-1/2}}\cdot(2x+3) \\
&= \frac{2x+3}{2(x^{2}+3x)^{\color{red}{1/2}}}
\end{align}

I've indicated in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ the part that is different from your answer.